# How to solve this task $T(n)=4T(n/4)+ \sqrt n\,$?

Tags: algorithms

I tried a lot but I can't solve it. Can someone explain it in an easy way? I want to calculate the running time.

$$n = 1 , O(1)$$

I've read this but it's not clear : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem_(analysis_of_algorithms)

I hope someone can do it.

Thanks

Comment: The critical exponent is $\log_4 4=1$. $f(n)=\mathcal{O}(n^{1/2})$. $1/2<1$, so this is case 1 in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem_(analysis_of_algorithms)#Generic_form It was not that hard, was it?

Comment: @Gary it´s hard in a way I can´t understand it ... I don´t know why. 
Can you give a calculation to it ? in case 1 is the last term n^2 but in my task its sqrt(n)

Comment: I do not know what is the problem. Look at the first line of the table. $c_{\text{crit}}=\log_b a= \log_4 4=1$. $f(n)=n^{1/2}=\mathcal{O}(n^c)$ with $c=1/2<1=c_{\text{crit}}$. Thus, $T(n)=\Theta(n^{c_{\text{crit}}})=\Theta(n)$. Do not look at the examples, look at the first big table at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem_(analysis_of_algorithms)#Generic_form

Comment: oh, ok slowly i understand it so the result is T (n) = o (n)

Comment: or is it O(n^1/2) ?

Comment: As I said $T(n)=\Theta(n)$. Note that $\Theta$ and $O$ are not the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Let $n=4^k$, then the recurrence relation can be written as
$$T(4^k)=4T(4^{k-1})+2^k.$$
Let $f(k)=T(4^k)/2^k$, then we have
$$f(k)=2f(k-1)+1.$$
This can be solved in many ways. For example,
\begin{align*}
f(k)&=2f(k-1)+1\\
2f(k-1)&=2^2f(k-2)+2\\
2^2f(k-2)&=2^3f(k-3)+2^2\\
\vdots&=\vdots\\
2^{k-2}f(2)&=2^{k-1}f(1)+2^{k-2}.
\end{align*}
Now add these to get
$$f(k)=2^{k-1}f(1)+\sum_{i=0}^{k-2}2^i=2^{k-1}f(1)+2^{k}-1$$
Thus
$$\frac{T(4^k)}{2^k}=2^{k-1}\frac{T(4)}{2}+2^k-1.$$
This implies:
$$T(4^k)=2^{2k-2}T(4)+2^{2k}-2^k=4^k\left(\underbrace{\frac{T(4)}{4}+1}_{\text{constant}}\right)-\sqrt{4^k}$$
Thus $T(n) \in \mathcal{O}(n)$.

Comment: Thanks.. but I don´t understand one thing. Why can you just say, let's assume we have 4 ^ k and not exactly my term, how did you solve this sqrt (n)?

Comment: @basics_typer the idea is that the problem of input size $n$ is being reduced to a problem with input size $n/4$. So at each stage you are reducing the size of the input for the problem by a factor of $4$. That is why we can assume that $n=4^k$ and as $k \to \infty$, then $n \to \infty$ as well.

Comment: So the running time is T(n) = O(n) ? or O(n^1/2)

Comment: @basics_typer Read the last line of the answer.

Comment: so T(n) = O(n) ?

Comment: @basics_typer Yes you seem to be not sure!!

Comment: I´m slowly getting it.

Comment: This ()=Θ() or this () = O() ?

Comment: @basics_typer WE can use this to also show that  $T(n)=\Theta(n)$